# Match the following regex: #*:*#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to find if a string contains a regular expression that starts and ends with a hash (#) and contains colon (:). All those should be matched on the same line

**Example:** hello to #some:test# and george **MATCH**

**Example:** hello to #:# world **NO MATCH**

**Example:** hello to #test:# world **NO MATCH**

**Example:** hello #:test# world **NO MATCH**

**Example:**

hello [newline]

to #some:test# world  **NO MATCH**

Thanks,
Yannis

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
@"\#.+:.+\#"
```

Breakdown:

```
\#   - Match a # character
.+   - Followed by one or more characters
:    - Followed by a : character
.+   - Followed by one or more characters
\#   - Followed by a # character
```

Note that `.` will match *any* character and is probably not the most efficient regular expression.

---

A non greedy version (more efficient):

```
@"\#[^:]+:[^#]+\#"

\#    - Match a # character
[^:]+ - Followed by one or more characters that are not :
:     - Followed by a : character
[^#]+ - Followed by one or more characters that are not #
\#    - Followed by a # character
```

Comment: You probably want to make the regex non-greedy.

Comment: Thanks Oded. How can I make this a bit more efficient then?